# How to upload two(2) image with caption to firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Hi guys I'm trying to upload 2(two) images on firebase with captions but it only uploads the first successfully then the field for 2nd image box (nimagetrail2) copies the bitmap on the 1st image box (nimagetrial) on the database. Can someone help me fix this so that each image gets its own bitmap?

XML file

```
  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagetrial"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/id" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagetrail2"
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="85dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imagetrial"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/payment_l" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editcap"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imagetrail2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imagetrail2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imagetrail2" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editcap2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Name"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editcap"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editcap"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editcap" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/editcap2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/editcap2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editcap2" />
```

Java code

```
    private ImageView nimagetrial, nimagetrial2;
private EditText neditcap,neditcap2;
private Button nsave;
private Bitmap bitmap,bitmap1;

private

Uri filepath,filepath1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_n_trial);

 nimagetrial = findViewById(R.id.imagetrial);
 nimagetrial2 = findViewById(R.id.imagetrail2);

 neditcap = findViewById(R.id.editcap);
 neditcap2 = findViewById(R.id.editcap2);

 nsave = findViewById(R.id.button3);

 nimagetrial.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         ImagePicker.Companion.with(nTrial.this)
                 .crop()
                 .compress(1040)
                 .maxResultSize(1270,1270)
                 .start(10);
     }
 });
 nimagetrial2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         ImagePicker.Companion.with(nTrial.this)
                 .crop()
                 .compress(1040)
                 .maxResultSize(1270,1270)
                 .start(20);
     }
 });

 nsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         savetrialData();
     }
 });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 10 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        filepath = data.getData();
        try{
            InputStream inputStream=getContentResolver().openInputStream(filepath);
            bitmap= BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            nimagetrial.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }else if (requestCode == 20 && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        filepath1 = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream1 = getContentResolver().openInputStream(filepath1);
            bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream1);
            nimagetrial2.setImageBitmap(bitmap1);

        }catch (Exception ex){

        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

}

private void savetrialData() {

    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Trail Uploader");
    dialog.show();

    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference uploader = storage.getReference("ntrial"+new Random().nextInt(50));

    uploader.putFile(filepath)
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                    uploader.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(@NonNull Uri uri) {

                            dialog.dismiss();
                            FirebaseDatabase mFD = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            DatabaseReference mDR = mFD.getReference("Trial");

                            nTrailModel obj = new nTrailModel(neditcap.getText().toString(), neditcap2.getText().toString(),uri.toString(),uri.toString());
                            mDR.child(neditcap.getText().toString()).setValue(obj);

                            neditcap.setText("");
                            neditcap2.setText("");
                            nimagetrial.setImageResource(R.drawable.id);
                            nimagetrial2.setImageResource(R.drawable.payment_l);

                        }
                    });

                }
            }).addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(@NonNull UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {

            float percent = (100*snapshot.getBytesTransferred())/snapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            dialog.setMessage(" Uploadind T_T: "+(int)percent+" %");
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: no errors sir but image duplication